# Fetching Image from excel sheet using Flask

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to fetch image from excel sheet using Flask. while doing it, in the below code it prints **Tracking No** data form excel sheet as fine but while printing the image, it returns **NAN**. Can we get the Image data from excel sheet? / How to do it?

```
if "bulk-upload" in request.form:
            file1 = request.files['files']
            data = pd.read_excel(file1, header=0)
            df = pd.DataFrame(data)
            for i in range(0, len(df)):
                print(df.iloc[i]['TrackingNo'])
                print(df.iloc[i]['image'])
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be an image file name?  You certainly can't literally store an IMAGE in a dataframe.

Comment: Okay!, Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: You will have to use a genuine xlsx reader like `openpyxl` or `xlrd`.